# Do calculation for array of values - Python

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy, plot, scipy

I am trying to calculate and plot the amplitude `amp` of the solution of a time dependent `t` differential equation of motion (see `rhs6`) as a function of `wd` for multiple values of the force coefficient `f` found in `f_array`.

So far I have got the code working for plotting `amp` against `wd` for a single value of `f`. The result is a resonance peak:

[image: Resonance peak]

The code for plotting `amp` against `wd` for one value of `f` (which produced the above image) is given below.

```
from pylab import *
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from numpy import *
import math

#Parameters.
k = 2.0
m = 1.0
w0 = (k/m)**(1/2)
alpha = 0.2
l = alpha/(2*m)
f = 1.0
wd = w0 + 0.025
beta = 0.2
t_fixed = 2.0

#Arrays.
t = linspace(0.0, 400.0, 400.0)
wd_array = linspace(w0-1.0, w0+1, 400.0)
f_array = linspace(10.0, 100.0, 3.0)

#Time step.
init_x = 0.0
init_v = 0.0
dx = 15.0
dv = 0.0
init_cond = [init_x,init_v]
init_cond2 = [init_x + dx,init_v + dv]

def rhs6(c,t,wd):
    c0dot = c[1]
    c1dot = -2*l*c[1] - w0*w0*c[0] + (f/m)*cos((wd)*t)
    return [c0dot, c1dot]

amp_array=[]
for wd in wd_array:
    res = odeint(rhs6, init_cond, t, args=(wd,))
    amp = max(res[:,0]) 
    amp_array.append(amp)

plot(wd_array, amp_array)
xlabel('Driving frequency, wd')
ylabel('Ampltiude, amp')    
show()
```

Now I wish to find `amp` against `wd` for multiple values of `f`. I have tried to do this by basically making a `for` loop statement over the `f_array`. However, my approach does not work and I get the error:

`setting an element with a sequence`.

As it's good to show an attempt, below is mine.

```
from pylab import *
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from numpy import *
import math

#Parameters.
k = 2.0
m = 1.0
w0 = (k/m)**(1/2)
alpha = 0.2
l = alpha/(2*m)
f = 1.0
wd = w0 + 0.025
beta = 0.2
t_fixed = 2.0

#Arrays.
t = linspace(0.0, 200.0, 200.0)
wd_array = linspace(w0-1.0, w0+1, 200.0)
f_array = linspace(10.0, 200.0, 3.0)

#Time step.
init_x = 0.0
init_v = 0.0
dx = 15.0
dv = 0.0
init_cond = [init_x,init_v]
init_cond2 = [init_x + dx,init_v + dv]

def rhs6(c,t,wd,f):
    c0dot = c[1]
    c1dot = -2*l*c[1] - w0*w0*c[0] + (f/m)*cos((wd)*t)
    return [c0dot, c1dot]

full_array = zeros(len(f_array))    
for index,force in enumerate(f_array):
    amp_list = []
    for wd in wd_array:
        res = odeint(rhs6, init_cond, t, args=(wd,force))
        amp = max(res[:,0]) 
        amp_list.append(amp)
        print(res)
    amp_array = array(amp_list)
    full_array[index] = amp_array

for f in full_array:
    plot(wd, amp)

show()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you attach the entire traceback, rather than just the error itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `full_array` is a numpy array and you're trying to set an element inside it as a list, hence the `setting an element with a sequence`.

To solve this you can instead create a two-dimensional numpy array and then set each of the rows to be `amp_array` as below

```
from pylab import *
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from numpy import *
import math

#Parameters.
k = 2.0
m = 1.0
w0 = (k/m)**(1/2)
alpha = 0.2
l = alpha/(2*m)
f = 1.0
wd = w0 + 0.025
beta = 0.2
t_fixed = 2.0

#Arrays.
t = linspace(0.0, 200.0, 200.0)
wd_array = linspace(w0-1.0, w0+1, 200.0)
f_array = linspace(10.0, 200.0, 3.0)

#Time step.
init_x = 0.0
init_v = 0.0
dx = 15.0
dv = 0.0
init_cond = [init_x,init_v]
init_cond2 = [init_x + dx,init_v + dv]

def rhs6(c,t,wd,f):
    c0dot = c[1]
    c1dot = -2*l*c[1] - w0*w0*c[0] + (f/m)*cos((wd)*t)
    return [c0dot, c1dot]

full_array = zeros((len(f_array),len(wd_array)))
for index,force in enumerate(f_array):
    amp_list = []
    for wd in wd_array:
        res = odeint(rhs6, init_cond, t, args=(wd,force))
        amp = max(res[:,0]) 
        amp_list.append(amp)
        # print(res)
    amp_array = array(amp_list)
    full_array[index,:] = amp_array

for f in full_array:
    plot(wd_array, f)

show()
```

Alternatively you could follow [gboffi's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26013620/3005188) advice and use either [`np.vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) or [`np.hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) to create your `full_array`.

Your `for` loop at the end to plot the arrays was also incorrect and so I've edited that. The graph looks like
[image: Plot]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I see my mistake now. Next up is to make a 3D plot of changing variables! This is at least possible given this framework :).